# How to fix SyntaxHighlighter to show cpp file without adding extra characters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntaxhighlighter

To show `C/C++` code with proper formatting, I found [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/) which is a javascript based syntax formatter for several language.

I have downloaded [the sample](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/download.php?sh_current) from the link of its page and edited `index.html` file for formatting the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<a+b<<endl;
    return 0;
}

</pre>

</html>
```

But it is not showing the C++ file properly. Rather it is showing the page like below:

[image]

Here you can test my snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCoreDefault.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
</head>


<body style="background: white; font-family: Helvetica">

<h1>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</h1>
<pre class="brush: cpp;">
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<a+b<<endl;
    return 0;
}

</pre>

</html>
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to html special characters '<', '>' etc. you can use the [PHP htmlspecialchars() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) to convert them to &lt,&gt etc. Then it will correctly parse the html special characters.

```html
<pre class="brush: cpp;">
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars('
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<a+b<<endl;
    return 0;
}')?>

</pre>
```

Comment: অস্থির! হ্যাস্টেগ সেলূট, হ্যাস্টেগ রেস্পেক্ট!!

Comment: মজা কম নাও। কোপাই প্রোজেক্ট চলতেছে হুম।

Comment: :O প্রোজেক্টতো কবেই শেষ!! :P